# Google Tag Manager: How to use "Custom Javascript" in a "Custom HTML Tag?"

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a custom javascript variable that is checking to see what the eventAction is so I can know whether to fire some conversion pixels or not. The custom Javascript is called "FacebookConversion" and looks like this:

```
function () {
  if({{eventAction}} == "completedSignUp" || {{eventAction}} == "upgrade" || {{eventAction}} == "frontUpgrade"){
    fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '{{eventValue}}', currency: 'USD'});
  }
  if({{eventAction}} == "submittedEnterpriseContactForm"){
    fbq('track', 'Lead');
  }
  console.log("HELLO");
  return;

}
```

Then I made a custom tag that fires on a page where the eventAction conversion takes place. The custom HTML tag is my conversion pixel and looks something like this:

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){....facebook code....);

fbq('init', 'xxxxxx');
fbq('track', "PageView");
  {{FacebookConversion}}
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxx&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing this right? Can I call {{FacebookConversion}} within my Custom Tag and have it run the custom Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Your methodology for firing these conditional tags is all wrong and you need to reconsider how you use Google Tag manager.  There is absolutely no need to use a custom variable in this setup.

To achieve your desired setup, you need 3 custom HTML **tags** each being fired off different triggers:

**Tag 1 - Main FB Pageview Tag**

This is the main pageview tag that fires on 'All Pages'

```
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){....facebook code....);

  fbq('init', 'xxxxxx');
  fbq('track', "PageView");
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxx&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

**Tag 2 - Lead Tag**

This is fired by a Trigger you need to create of type = custom event and with value = "submittedEnterpriseContactForm"

```
<script>
  fbq('track', 'Lead');
</script>
```

**Tag 3 - conversion Tag**

This is fired by any of 3 Triggers you need to create of type = custom event and with value = "completedSignUp" or value="upgrade" or value="frontUpgrade"

```
<script>
   fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '{{eventValue}}', currency: 'USD'});
</script>
```

And that's it.  The triggers decide when to fire tags so no need for any additional logic.  You may need to play about with the variables you use in the conversion tag to get the values but thats pretty much setup dependent.

Comment: Your way is very simple and I'm sure it works, but it's a little too obvious and doesn't help me reduce the number of tags and triggers I'm using. We have other partners as well besides Facebook such as Twitter, LinkedIn, and Bing, etc. If I start making 3 tags and 3 triggers per partner then GTM is going to get messy pretty quickly. Plus it violates the DRY principal.

Comment: With due respect your attempted way doesn't work for the simple reason that GTM wasn't designed to be used like that.  GTM is designed to be used in the manner i've described.  Yes there are ways to minimise tags and triggers but having worked on some of the largest and most sophisticated GTM (and Adobe TM and TealiumiQ) installations I can assure you that the best way is to manage large quantities of tags/triggers/variables by using the gtm filing system and a well thought out naming convention.  I'm not sure how it violates DRY but it certainly adheres to KISS.  Best of luck!

Comment: @asolberg Chaining tags is actually a common practice and if your aim is to minimize the amount of tags then you'd have a hard time achieving your goal